# Not receiving welcome emails on creating a new partner user

Tags: community, email, partner-communities, partner

I am not receiving the welcome emails on creating new partner user. Any idea what can be the issue with it? I received for my other two orgs but just for one org I am not getting emails.

Comment: Can you check the Email Deliverability Settings for new Org? If it is set as "No access" then Salesforce Prevents all outbound email to and from users.

Comment: @Devendra yes i tried this. I used tested Email Deliverability also. No emails were generated when I did this. But same thing if I do for other org I am getting all the emails. So, I don't think it will be IP issue.

Comment: You need to set email Deliverability other than "No Access".

Comment: Its already done.

Comment: Are you still facing an issue?

Comment: Yes. We have raised a case with salesforce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raised case with SF and they solved it.

Comment: What did they do to resolve it?